# How to add a image_send_to_editor filter to a specific wp_editor instance

Tags: wordpress, plugins, add-filter, wp-editor

I want to add the filter to a custom wp_editor in a metabox. Is there a way to get the editor_id so it doesnt get applied to all editors? Thanks!

```
    $args = array(
         'quicktags' => true,
         'media_buttons' => true,
           'tinymce' => array(
                'toolbar1' => 'p123553_mce_button_headings,p123553_mce_button_quotes,',
                'toolbar2' => false,
                'plugins' => '',
              ),
            );
    wp_editor('This is the default text!', 'p123553', $args);


public function p123553_filter_image_send_to_editor($content)
{
    $content .= $editor_id.'<p>Unicorns are awesome.</p>';

    return $content;
}


add_filter('image_send_to_editor',  'p123553_filter_image_send_to_editor');
```

Comment: I have created a custom wp_editor.  

wp_editor('This is the default text!', 'ia_designer_mce_editor', $args);

Comment: Goot to know. But still i cant get the `$editor_id` inside the `image_send_to_editor` filter so i can specify which wp_editor to use.

Comment: I edited the question and added the code that i use to create the editor. `image_send_to_editor` is the name of the filter ( doesnt exist in the options table ). The filter works properly. It changes the output of the insert image html in the insert media window. The 'custom' editor is a normal wp_editor loaded in a meta box in the posts.

Comment: Yes i know thanks… Try to find in your database option table, the right associated key  for `p123553` custom editor (ID), please… With that info it will be easy to make a conditional inside your function

Comment: Zero rows returned for 'p123553' in the option table

Comment: I dont think its stored in the database at all.

Comment: Yea i sorry, misspelled. Here is the query ->  `SELECT * 
FROM  wp_options WHERE option_name =  p123553`

Comment: And with `SELECT * FROM 'wp_options' WHERE 'option_name' LIKE '%editor%'` you will get some raws… then try visually to find `p123553` in 'option_value' key … or directly `SELECT * FROM 'wp_options' WHERE 'option_value' LIKE '%p123553%'` … then if you find it … dont comment. update your question. and try to delete old not useful comments